# How do I convert this equation from Iverson brackets to make use of the Heaviside function?

Tags: summation

I have the equation

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 2^{i}[0 \leq x - 2^{i}][x - 2^{i + 1} < 0]$

and I would like to convert the Iverson brackets to the Heaviside function.

I've read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49963/define-a-graph-with-segments-or-boundaries/54750#54750) but I'm still a bit confused as to how this would work inside the summation.

EDIT:

If it helps, I believe I've reduced it to

$u_1(x) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{i-1}u_{2^i}(x)$

Comment: Iverson brackets definition for the Heaviside function $H(x)$ is $H(x) = [0\leq x]$ (except for $x=0$ where the Heaviside is usually defined to be $1/2$). Ignoring the $x=0$ issue then $H(x-2^i)H(2^{i+1}-x)$ should do the trick.

Comment: @Winther I understand - it seems very simple when looking at your response. Thanks very much!

Comment: btw you can remove the summation all togeather. Given $x$ there is only one integer $n$ s.t. $2^n \leq x < 2^{n+1}$ and the only non-zero term in the series is the $n$'th term so: $\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^i [0\leq x - 2^i][x-2^{i+1} < 0] = 2^{n} = 2^{\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor}$ where $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ is the [floor-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: @Winther That's what I just started! Thanks again, this has been very helpful!